# issue with tkinter and variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When i run this i get an error that i dont understand

I have tried editing variables to fix the issue however it has not worked

```
from tkinter import *
cookie = 0
am = 1

def cookieFunc():
    global cookie
    global am
    cookie = cookie + am
    print(cookie)

def grandma():
    global cookie
    global am
    if cookie >= 10:
        cookie = cookie - 10
        am = am + 0.5

def farm():
    global cookie
    global am
    if cookie >= 100:
        cookie = cookie - 100
        am = am + 5

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
cookie = Button(root, text='cookie', command=cookieFunc)
cookie.pack()
grandma = Button(root, text='grandma', command=grandma)
grandma.pack()
farm = Button(root, text='farm', command=farm)
farm.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When you click cookie it should add 1 to cookie
grandma should add 0.5 to am which is the amount of cookies you get per click
farm should add 5 to am

Comment: I also don't understand this error because you didn't add full error message in question.

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: You redeclared variable `cookie`.

Answer (score 2):

You have problem because you use the same name for different variables

```
cookie = 0
cookie = Button(...)
```

so you think that you add two integers in

```
cookie + am
```

but Python see

```
Button + am
```

Similar with

```
def farm()
farm = Button(...)

def grandma()
grandma = Button(...)
```

Working code use `button_cookie`, `button_farm`

```
from tkinter import *

cookie = 0
am = 1

def cookieFunc():
    global cookie
    global am

    cookie = cookie + am
    print(cookie, am)

def grandma():
    global cookie
    global am

    if cookie >= 10:
        cookie = cookie - 10
        am = am + 0.5
    print(cookie, am)

def farm():
    global cookie
    global am

    if cookie >= 100:
        cookie = cookie - 100
        am = am + 5
    print(cookie, am)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

button_cookie = Button(root, text='cookie', command=cookieFunc)
button_cookie.pack()

button_grandma = Button(root, text='grandma', command=grandma)
button_grandma.pack()

button_farm = Button(root, text='farm', command=farm)
button_farm.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thorough answer @furas, and congrats on the 50k

Answer (score 1):

At the start you declare int variable `cookie`:

```
cookie = 0
```

After that you assign `Button()` to this variable:

```
cookie = Button(root, text='cookie', command=cookieFunc)
```

I think, it's not what you want to do. **Just rename one of variables.**

*P.S. try to use IDE, it'll highlight you variable which have been shadowed.*